# What is the most efficient way to order mongoDB collections

Tags: mongodb, performance

I'm using mongo db to store web server traffic data.
On each page visit i want to store multiple data types such as:

- HTTP request info
- Client analytics info
- etc.

these data types are received from different endpoints for different domains, and sometimes not all of them.

On each incoming data i would like to store the raw data so that eventually i could query the different data types on specific user/domain.

My current DB structure is:

**collections:**

- data_type1
- data_type2
  ... (more collections for each data_type)
- domains (concentrating all domains referring to related data_types)
- users (concentrating all users referring to related data_types)

**documents:**

data_type1 : {_id:ABCD, data: raw_data(including user&domain)}

data_type2 : {_id:XYZ, data: raw_data(including user&domain)}

domains : {domain:xxx.xx, data_type1:[ABCD, (other related)], data_type2:[XYZ, (other_related)]}

users : {user:qwerty, data_type1:[(user data_type1 related docs _id)], data_type2:[(user data_type2 related docs _id)]}

I tried different ways, my concern is that for each user or domain the data_types referring arrays could grow infinitely especially when processing millions of requests.

Is this order considered efficient? can you propose better structure?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found guidance for better structure in this blog post:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3